# problem with $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Tags: php, ip

i used $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and it returns client ip address (IP address from which the user is viewing the current page) but at now (and same code) it returns host ip address (i checked ip address with ip location).  problem is with host or  what?
thank u.

Comment: You wouldnt be visiting it from your host by coincidence?

Comment: Do you use some kind of proxy?

Comment: no. i checked several times. i dont use proxy

Comment: Gumbo meant a proxy on the server side, not on the client side (something like a httpd accelerator).

Answer (score 12):

You should query for `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` first and if it isn't assigned use `REMOTE_ADDR`.

Comment: i use HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR at now and it returns correct ip. but why problem with REMOTE_ADDR?

Comment: Because there is a proxy between you and the server, and you get the address of the proxy as REMOTE_ADDR. HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR is the IP of the client using the proxy.

Comment: @imez: As @Rosh has already pointed out there must be a proxy between you and the server and if you query `REMOTE_ADDR` you will get the IP of the proxy server. If you check for `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` first then a lot of the time the proxy will populate this with the `real` IP address.

Answer (score 4):

@James @imez

By default the client IP is in $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. When the user enters your site using a PROXY server (HTTP gateway) it tells you who it's proxing for (HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR) and will give it's own Proxy IP in $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].

Anonymous proxies will omit HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR or simply lie to you.

Knowing you have a real client IP isn't possible.

Comment: I have stated that in my comment on my answer. It's never a *guarentee* that the real IP address is in `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` but like I said, most of the time it is.

Comment: what if it happens on localhost? how do i know i use proxy (that surely i don't use)?

Answer (score 2):

I have to mention that the array key is case-sensitive, and should be upper-case:

```
var_dump($_SERVER['remote_addr']);
echo "\n";
var_dump($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Output:

```
Notice: Undefined index: remote_addr in /home/adam/public_html/2011/01/04/foo.php on line 3
NULL

string(15) "10.0.1.51"
```

I would `var_dump($_SERVER)` just to evaluate the state of your world, and go from there.

Comment: Dumping the whole of $_SERVER is a good idea - I discovered the real IP address behind a proxy I'm working with in HTTP_CLIENT_IP that way...