# How to use $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] in PHP websocket server

Tags: php, websocket

I have am using websocket and trying to merge with my custom PHP app and Mysql database. In Database I store IP, ClientID and username when user connects to server. These infromation are to be used when user disconnect from websocket server or sends message. I run server.php with **php server.php**

The server page is https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat/blob/master/server.php

As mentioned above I stored necessary information in Mysql database to identify which users sends message, disconnect and connect.

So for that I need to identify my own mechine IP for further identification with various clients. So when I try to use

```
<?php 
    echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

in server.php. It gives an error saying undefined.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594823/problem-with-serverremote-addr

Comment: Didn't help. Would you help me solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most accurate way to retrieve a user's correct IP address in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634782/what-is-the-most-accurate-way-to-retrieve-a-users-correct-ip-address-in-php)

Comment: Not a duplicate of either of those, because WebSockets is not HTTP.

Comment: Also, that FlynsArmy websocket server is implementing an old, insecure draft version of the websocket standard. For the sake of you and your users, find a server that implements RFC 6455 ( https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455 ), also known as Version 13.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't.**

WebSockets does not deal with web requests.  The `$_SERVER` superglobal does not get populated because it does not make sense to populate it.

Deal with the socket connections directly.

You most likely want to play around with [`socket_getsockname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-getsockname.php).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

and check if it prints...  [REMOTE_ADDR] => .......

But if you are after clients IP, 
as a PHP developer I use following code

```
    $ip=NULL;
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) 
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) 
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else 
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: No it throws **PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in**. It neither prints SESSION nor GET. But it prints anything from database if we use. Thank you

Comment: What about using var_dump($_SERVER);

Comment: Please use `var_dump($_SERVER)`.

Comment: var_dump($_SERVER) worked, it gave me bunch of array. Going through to pick something useful... It seems I couldn't get IP address of my computer. Anyways ..Appreciate it.